# Evaluating all elisp org source blocks in buffer

Tags: org-babel

Is there a way to evaluate all elisp org source blocks in the current
buffer?  The best I have now is: save to file, and do:

```
(org-babel-load-file buffer-file-name)
```

Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 5):

You can execute *all source blocks* (elisp and otherwise) with `org-babel-execute-buffer` which is bound to <kbd>C-c C-v b</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to skip the (repeated) confirmation prompts?

Comment: Maybe you can set [org-babel-confirm-evaluate](https://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html) to avoid prompts.